# Querying posts from current category, using a variable as array argument

Tags: posts, categories, query, query-posts, urls

I been banging my head around on this one.
I'm making a custom catagory template page, and I want to pull up all posts in the same category as stated in the URL (domain.com/category/example). But when I try to this as a variable it doesn't seem to work, and it pulls up all posts. Regardless of the category.

The code below is what I've been trying.

```
                  // set up or arguments for our custom query
                      $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                      $catPath = single_cat_title();
                      echo $catPath; 
                      $query_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'category_name' => $catPath,
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'paged' => $paged
                      );
```

Answer (score 0):

Already figured it out and seems to be working just fine.

```
                  // set up or arguments for our custom query
                      $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
                      $category = single_cat_title('', false);
                      $query_args = array(
                        'post_type' => 'post',
                        'category_name' => $category,
                        'posts_per_page' => 3,
                        'paged' => $paged
                      );
```